# Emulator Error: System Process and Launcher UI Stopped

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-emulator, android-logcat

I get this error for system_process(351) from logcat, when ever I start Emulator on my Ubuntu x64 14.04 LTS

```
    05-30 03:23:23.789      351-351/system_process E/PowerManagerService-JNI﹕ Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
05-30 03:23:37.213      351-351/system_process E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Can't open consumer IR HW Module, error: -2
05-30 03:23:38.002      351-441/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
05-30 03:23:38.078      351-441/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
05-30 03:23:40.988      351-351/system_process E/WifiConfigStore﹕ associatedPartialScanPeriodMilli set to 20000
05-30 03:23:43.360      351-351/system_process E/Fingerprint-JNI﹕ Can't open fingerprint HW Module, error: -2
05-30 03:23:43.781      351-351/system_process E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 16 frames from WAL file /data/system/locksettings.db-wal
05-30 03:23:43.910      351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage﹕ Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-30 03:23:43.912      351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage﹕ Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-30 03:23:48.754      351-446/system_process E/VoldConnector﹕ NDC Command {5 volume mount /storage/sdcard} took too long (2797ms)
05-30 03:23:54.719      351-351/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {1 bandwidth enable} took too long (8830ms)
05-30 03:23:56.556      351-351/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {2 firewall disable} took too long (1725ms)
05-30 03:23:57.850      351-351/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {4 bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152} took too long (1127ms)
05-30 03:23:58.419      351-471/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
05-30 03:23:58.422      351-471/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
05-30 03:23:58.619      351-351/system_process E/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Ignoring setImeWindowStatus due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
05-30 03:23:59.404      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:23:59.414      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:24:00.971      351-351/system_process E/LocationManagerService﹕ no geocoder provider found
05-30 03:24:00.972      351-351/system_process E/FlpHardwareProvider﹕ Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
05-30 03:24:00.972      351-351/system_process E/LocationManagerService﹕ FLP HAL not supported
05-30 03:24:01.098      351-351/system_process E/LocationManagerService﹕ Unable to bind FLP Geofence proxy.
05-30 03:24:01.099      351-351/system_process E/ActivityRecognitionHardware﹕ Error hw_get_module: -2
05-30 03:24:01.100      351-351/system_process E/LocationManagerService﹕ Hardware Activity-Recognition not supported.
05-30 03:24:06.516      351-351/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
05-30 03:24:06.970      351-351/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
05-30 03:24:15.846      351-463/system_process E/ConnectivityService﹕ Failed to find Messenger in unregisterNetworkFactory
05-30 03:24:34.061      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:24:36.634      351-374/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in com.android.systemui
    PID: 512
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
    Load: 8.32 / 2.56 / 0.9
    CPU usage from 4973ms to -18546ms ago:
    26% 351/system_server: 16% user + 9.8% kernel / faults: 8830 minor 2 major
    14% 54/surfaceflinger: 7.9% user + 6.9% kernel / faults: 11 minor
    11% 774/com.android.launcher: 9.4% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 10923 minor 6 major
    8.8% 751/zygote: 5.6% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 6687 minor 8 major
    7.7% 512/com.android.systemui: 5.4% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 4516 minor 1 major
    1.1% 62/debuggerd: 0.3% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 2491 minor
    2.9% 60/adbd: 0.5% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 1314 minor
    2.7% 100/bootanimation: 1.1% user + 1.6% kernel
    1.9% 710/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 1.4% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 1510 minor
    1.2% 26/mtdblock1: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
    1.2% 803/android.process.acore: 0.9% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 601 minor
    1.1% 49/logd: 0.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 27 minor
    0.6% 631/android.process.media: 0.4% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1064 minor 6 major
    0.5% 52/servicemanager: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
    0.3% 65/mediaserver: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 10 minor
    0.3% 221/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel
    0.1% 63/rild: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
    0.1% 94/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0% 25/mtdblock0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 41/jbd2/mtdblock1-: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 964/sh: 0% user + 0% kernel
    100% TOTAL: 62% user + 36% kernel + 0.5% softirq
    CPU usage from 16102ms to 17141ms later:
    20% 774/com.android.launcher: 18% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 1749 minor
    13% 774/ndroid.launcher: 12% user + 1.1% kernel
    4.4% 788/GCDaemon: 4.4% user + 0% kernel
    1.1% 937/RenderThread: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel
    0.5% 787/HeapTrimmerDaem: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
    16% 351/system_server: 14% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 9 minor
    4.1% 374/ActivityManager: 2.4% user + 1.6% kernel
    3.3% 358/JDWP: 3.3% user + 0% kernel
    3.3% 360/FinalizerDaemon: 3.3% user + 0% kernel
    2.4% 537/Binder_4: 1.6% user + 0.8% kernel
    1.6% 736/Binder_6: 0.8% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 373/android.bg: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 625/Binder_5: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 839/Binder_7: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    16% 54/surfaceflinger: 6.9% user + 9.5% kernel
    3.4% 54/surfaceflinger: 1.7% user + 1.7% kernel
    3.4% 92/VSyncThread: 0.8% user + 2.6% kernel
    2.6% 85/Binder_1: 0.8% user + 1.7% kernel
    1.7% 97/surfaceflinger: 0.8% user + 0.8% kernel
    1.7% 479/Binder_4: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 86/DispSync: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 90/Binder_2: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 96/EventThread: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 117/Binder_3: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    4.5% 751/com.android.phone: 2.2% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 21 minor
    4.5% 751/m.android.phone: 2.2% user + 2.2% kernel
    3.9% 512/com.android.systemui: 2.8% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 635 minor
    2.8% 512/ndroid.systemui: 2.8% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 955/AsyncTask #1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 960/RenderThread: 0% user + 0% kernel
    5.2% 60/adbd: 0.8% user + 4.3% kernel / faults: 74 minor
    2.6% 200/adbd: 0.8% user + 1.7% kernel
    1.7% 60/adbd: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
    2.7% 631/android.process.media: 1.6% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 244 minor
    2.7% 631/d.process.media: 1.6% user + 1.1% kernel
    2.8% 49/logd: 2.8% user + 0% kernel
    2.8% 226/logd.reader.per: 2.8% user + 0% kernel
    2.6% 100/bootanimation: 0% user + 2.6% kernel
    2.6% 112/BootAnimation: 0% user + 2.6% kernel
    1.6% 803/android.process.acore: 1.6% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    1.1% 844/ContactsProvide: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
    0.5% 858/Binder_3: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
    1.1% 710/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 1.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 35 minor
    1.1% 846/erunigram.en_US: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
    100% TOTAL: 79% user + 20% kernel
05-30 03:24:36.986      351-374/system_process E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 512
05-30 03:24:40.696      351-463/system_process E/ConnectivityService﹕ RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=2, legacyType=-1, [] ]
05-30 03:24:40.896      351-365/system_process E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 512
05-30 03:24:48.669      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:24:48.782      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:24:49.229      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:24:49.253      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:25:01.752      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:25:01.754      351-351/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:25:01.986      351-463/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {18 idletimer add eth0 5 0} took too long (942ms)
05-30 03:25:05.967      351-374/system_process E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 631
05-30 03:25:10.162      351-455/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {20 bandwidth setiquota eth0 9223372036854775807} took too long (3399ms)
05-30 03:25:13.027      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:25:13.029      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:25:13.035      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:25:13.037      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:25:13.064      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:25:13.066      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-30 03:25:13.077      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-30 03:25:13.131      351-373/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
```

And also from com.android.systemui

```
05-30 03:25:02.692      992-992/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
05-30 03:25:03.740      992-992/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
```

According to my research on this problem, I centre it to issues with the sensor manager regarding the bluetooth emulation.

I have tired the solutions of editing the config file or wiping the user data.